# Sencha Touch App freeze when multitouch / Android

Tags: android, extjs, touch, freeze, pinch

I built a sencha touch (2.1.0) app and tested it on my Samsung Galaxy S2 (Android 4.0.3).
Once I did that with the native build command of snecha cmd and another I wrapped it with phonegap.
Both times I've got a freeze when I touch the screen with two fingers at the same time.
I cannot press a button or scroll anymore.

Has anyone a solution for that problem?

I also read the post in the Sencha forum (http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?249581-Multi-touch-and-phonegap), but that did not work for me or I'm doing something wrong.

Any help would be appreciable.

Comment: Does Android logcat show anything when running via PhoneGap? Does this cause the app to completely freeze, requiring a force quit? I've seen this plenty before but it never caused any kind of freeze for me.

Comment: Yes, this is the error, logcat shows when freezed:
"D/CordovaLog(12706): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'point' of undefined"

Sometimes I can get out of the freeze with a pinch-out and sometimes  I have to quit the App.

Answer (score 0):

I recently came across this problem and visited the Sencha Forum link you mentioned and implemented it in my code which achieve the following.
1. With the fix incorporated app will never freeze with simultaneous tap.
2. You will have to tap somewhere on the screen one more time, after you simultaneously tapped at two or more points earlier.

Note: The issue is reproducible only with android 4.0.x and Sencha 2.1.

**A big thanks to TROELS from Sencha Forum**
**In your app.js place the if condition outside your Ext.application as shown below**

```
Ext.application({
    name:xyz
    requires:[abc]
    //other stuffs
    });

    if(Ext.os.is.Android && Ext.os.version.equals(4.0)) {

        Ext.define('app.overrides.TouchGesture', {
            override: 'Ext.event.publisher.TouchGesture',

            reset: function(e){
                if(Ext.os.version.equals(4.0) && this.currentTouchesCount > 0){
                    e.changedTouches = Ext.Object.getValues(this.currentTouches);
                    this.onTouchEnd(e);
                }
            }
        });


            window.orgPinchEndMethod = Ext.event.recognizer.Pinch.prototype.end;
            Ext.define('app.overrides.Pinch', {
            override: 'Ext.event.recognizer.Pinch',

            end: function(e){
            var wasTracking = this.isTracking,
            result = window.orgPinchEndMethod.apply(this, arguments);
            if(wasTracking){
                this._resetDetection(e);
            }
            return result;
        },

            _resetDetection: function(e){
                var tg = Ext.event.Dispatcher.getInstance().getPublishers().touchGesture;
                setTimeout(function(){
                    tg.reset(e);
                }, 0);
            }
           });

     }
```